# How to upgrade ExpressionEngine version 3 to 4

Tags: php, expressionengine

How to upgrade ExpressionEngine version from 3 to 4.

My current Version of EE is 3.4.6 and I want upgrade with 4.3.8 or latest.

Comment: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/updating.html

Comment: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/updating.html

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be much of a problem. Most addons that wotk with EE3 also function with EE4/5
Mainly you follow the instructions in the docs. That means do a manual update from 3 to 4 and when you're on V4 you can click the one click update button that'll update the rest automatically